# Can an array be ordered both ascendant and descendant for bsearch to work?

Tags: c, bsearch

From [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/)

> Because this function may be optimized to use a non-linear search
> algorithm (presumably a binary search), *the elements that compare less
> than key using compar should precede those that compare equal, and
> these should precede those that compare greater*. This requirement is
> fulfilled by any array ordered with the same criteria used by compar
> (as if sorted with qsort).

- In the quoted text, what does it mean the italic part?
- Also, can I order the array descendant? or only ascendant?
- What else kind of order can the elements inside the array being sorted can it be?

Comment: The italic text means that the array is sorted in the ascending order. What is unclear?!

Comment: So the answer would be the array should always be in ascendant order and only in ascendat order?

Comment: These notions (ascending and descending orders)  are interchangeable. For example using a negation   of the result of the comparison function you can get one order from another order. Usually these terms are used for ordering according to the built-in operator <.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the quoted text, what does it mean the italic part?

The text “*the elements that compare less than key using compar should precede those that compare equal, and these should precede those that compare greater*” means that if you have two elements of the array, say `a[i]` and `a[j]`, and `compar` reports `a[i]` is “less than” `a[j]`, then `i` should be less than `j` (by their integer values), and, if `compar` reports `a[i]` is “greater than” `a[j]`, then `i` should be greater than `j`. In other words, the relationship between the positions of the elements in the array matches the relationship between their values as reported by `compar`.

(Note that these words only tell you about the ordering for elements that `compar` reports as less than or greater than. It does not impose any constraint on ordering for elements that `compar` reports as equal.)

> Also, can I order the array descendant? or only ascendant?

The `compar` function **defines** what the ordering is. You may have some notion in your head that 3 < 4 or “apple” is before “banana”, but `compar` can be any ordering. For this purpose, “ascending” means progress in the order defined; it does not mean necessarily 3 before 4 or “apple” before “banana”. You could, for example, sort integers according to their low bits first, then their second lowest bits, then their third lowest bits, and so on, instead of by their usual values.

> What else kind of order can the elements inside the array being sorted can it be?

Any total ordering can be used. A total ordering gives one relationship between any two elements (<, =, or >) and does not contain any “contradictions” to putting the elements in order. Formally, for any x, y, and z, a total ordering satisfies: x ≤ y and y ≤ x implies x = y, x ≤ y and y ≤ z implies x ≤ z, and either x ≤ y or y ≤ x.

Any relationship that satisfies those requirements can be used.

Comment: The compar function must implement a total ordering, not a partial ordering. See 7.22.5/4. Total ordering does not mean that there cannot be equivalence classes; it means that for any two values x and y, exactly one of `x<y`, `x>y` and `x=y` is true. The order created by the subset relationship is partial, for example. Floating point comparison is partial if NaN is a possible value. For bsearch, the key appears in every comparison, so the comparison function doesn't have to be total over every possible pair of values, if the key is somehow restricted.

Comment: (Usually we use a boolean operator ≤ to define partial/total order: `x=y` is defined as `x≤y and y≤x`. But qsort/bsearch require a three-way comparison function with an explicit equality return value. The criterion above is a translation.)

Answer (score 1):

This part of the quote

> the elements that compare less than key using compar should precede
> those that compare equal, and these should precede those that compare
> greater.

means that the array should be ordered such a way that all elements that are "less" than key according to the used comparison function (the function that is specified as an argument of calls of the standard functions `qsort` and `bsearch`) must precede the elements that are "equal" to key according to the same comparison function and the last in turn must precede the elements that are "greater" than key according to the comparison function.

When we are speaking about ascending or descending order of elements of an array we mean that there is defined the operator < (not necessary the built-in operator < but some user defined function) for elements of the array such that for ascending order this relation !( a[j] < a[i] ) where i < j is kept for all elements of the array while for descending order the relation is !( a[i] < a[j] )

For the standard functions `qsort` and `bsearch` the comparison function that sets an order is declared and defined the following way

```
int cmp(const void *, const void *)
```

and shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first pointed element (or key for `bsearcj`) is considered, respectively, to be less than, to match, or to be greater than the second pointed array element.

You can use the function `qsort` for example to partition an array according some criterion.

Here is a demonstrative program that sorts an array at first according to the criterion that each element with an odd value is "less" than each element with an even value and then vice versa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmp1( const void *left, const void *right )
{
    int a = *( const int * )left;
    int b = *( const int * )right;
    
    return b % 2 - a % 2;
}

int cmp2( const void *left, const void *right )
{
    return -cmp1( left, right );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % N;
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    qsort( a, N, sizeof( int ), cmp1 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( int ), cmp2 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
4 8 8 9 5 2 9 0 1 2 
9 5 9 1 4 8 8 2 0 2 
4 8 8 2 0 2 9 5 9 1
```

You can use the function `bsearch` with the corresponding comparison function to find an element with a specified key.

In this case this array

```
9 5 9 1 4 8 8 2 0 2
```

is sorted in the ascending order according to the function `cmp1` and this array

```
4 8 8 2 0 2 9 5 9 1
```

is sorted in the ascending order according to the function `cmo2`.

On the other hand, you can consider the first array relative to the second array as it is sorted in the ascending order while the second array is sorted in the descending order according to the comparison function `cmp1`. And vice versa if to consider sorting of the arrays according to the comparison function `cmp2`.

But if you are using the function `bsearch` for the binary search then you should provide an order of the array specifying an appropriate comparison function such a way that

> the elements that compare less than key using compar should precede
> those that compare equal, and these should precede those that compare
> greater.

That is it is always supposed when you use the function `bsearch` that the array is sorted in the ascending order according to the comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

> In the quoted text, what does it mean the italic part?

The array must be ordered as with `qsort` using the same `compar` function. **Note:** All possible `qsort` results are good for that, regardless the original array order (which may give different results, but still good orders for `bsearch`).

---

> Also, can I order the array descendant? or only ascendant?

Only as with `qsort` using the same comparing function (AKA: it must be ascending).

---

> What else kind of order can the elements inside the array being sorted can it be?

None, but note multiple `qsort` results are possible with multiple initial orders of the same elements.

Comment: Yes, both ordering would be correct for a correct `bsearch` result, as stated in the docs: first, all the elements that would be less, then the equals and finally the grater. Isn't that what it means?

Comment: I mean, both orders would be the result of `qsort` ordering (depending on original array), so both are good arrays to be used with `bsearch`.

Comment: It's not what I said. When saying `must be ordered as with qsort` does not means `qsort must be used`. The array must match **some** `qsort` result, not necessarily the result from applying `qsort` to the original array. In fact, it's just a cite from the original docs quoted in the question: `(as if sorted with qsort)`.

Comment: Then you are saying the original doc at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) is ambiguous?

Comment: It's obvious none human scripture is infallible, but I can understand the word `as` when looking for similitude and not necessarily equality. Considering c++ docs are old enough and curated by lots of people, maybe what it says is exactly what it wants to say and how the code works.

Comment: You are completely right. Sorry for my behavior. Just added some extra notes to improve the answer.